# How to get X,Y,Z coordinate values from a point?

Tags: loops, command-line, tcl, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I have N number (user input) of point data.
each point have X, Y, Z coordinate. I want to use this in a tool automation code.
in the below code user is giving number of points in 1st line.
the number of points are stored in set s1
after that it extract the X, Y, Z coords value in s1x, s1y and s1z set
this sets then called in createplane command (ignore $px $py $pz)

Now I want to call each point and extract the x, y, z coords value and place it in createplane command untill the number of user input points.

Because of tool restrictions n policy can't share the proper tool code. This is a rough code or you can say idea.

```
createpanel points 1 "Select points"
set s1 [mark points 1]
foreach {N} $s1 {
    set s1x [ getentityvalue $s1 "globalx" 0 ]
    set s1y [ getentityvalue $s1 "globaly" 0 ]
    set s1z [ getentityvalue $s1 "globalz" 0 ]
    createplane 1 $px $py $pz $s1x $s1y $s1z
    createvector 1 $px $py $pz
}
```

if you have any idea to solve this problem please help.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to get one point from somewhere? Do you know how to provide a group of points to the entity that needs them? We can help with the code to connect those two things up. (Also, I made your code look more like standard Tcl code by adding newlines and indentation; hope I got that right...)

Comment: Thanks for correcting it. I have no idea about how to provide a group of points to the required entity, can you please explain more.

Comment: The problem is that there's so many different places that coordinates could come from _in general_ (immediate user input, files, databases, generator programs, etc.) that **we have to narrow things down to be able to answer your question at all.** _Generically_ we can do some things to do with how to route data around inside Tcl, but specific help really requires knowing where things are coming from and where they're going to.

Comment: whatever extra data you required I will provide it. This software I am using is call Hypermesh. Where node (Point) is the entity which has X, Y, Z coords value according global axis system. The coords values are run inside the tool and generates a tcl script for whatever we operation perform in it. But it will generate for 1 point at a time. For the automation purpose I need it in loop. it is possible to store this  coords data in an excel and then use the coords value when necessary, But how I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking, to update the points of a collection of entities, you'd do:

```
foreach item [getEntityCollectionAsList] {
    set coords [getNewCoordinatesFor $item]
    setCoordinatesOf $item $coords
}
```

That's a *very* high-level picture! The entity collection could be in a database or on a screen or in a simulation or any number of other things. The new coordinates could be obtained from many different places (including by directly asking the user, though that would become annoying for large numbers of points). It also doesn't say what the format of the coordinates themselves are (or how many points each item has) or how exactly the new coordinates are set. "All" you have to do is provide implementations of `getEntityCollectionAsList`, `getNewCoordinatesFor`, and `setCoordinatesOf`, probably changing the names in the process (and maybe adding other arguments as required); that could be easy or difficult.

Without knowing where the data is coming from or going to, it's hard to say much specific. The above pattern is *very* likely to feature in some form, but there's a vast amount of variation still possible.